# How to merge two arrays of dates and keep the order for other array

Tags: javascript, date

I have this code:

```
var dates1 = ['1/2021', '1/2021', '12/2020'];
var values1 = ['-2500', '-150', '-10000'];

var dates2 = ['2/2021', '3/2021', '1/2021'];
var values2 = ['3000', '1000', '3000'];
```

What I need is to merge the `dates1` with `dates2`, and keep the same order for `values1` and `values2` adding a 0 for the dates that has none `values`, so the result would be this:

```
var dates = ['12/2020', '1/2021', '2/2021', '3/2021'];
var values1 = ['-10000', '-2650', '0', '0'];
var values2 = ['0', '3000', '3000', '1000'];
```

To merge the arrays of dates I'm using this code:

```
var dates = dates1.concat(dates2);
```

I just don't know how can I keep the same order for `values1` and `values2` adding a 0 for none values.
Any suggestion ? Thank you !

Comment: seems like a key/value solution would be a better fit for this.  Have you thought about using a dictionary instead?  If so what's the blocker?

Comment: A `for` loop would be a good start. Combined with an `.indexOf()` or `.includes()` and a `.splice()`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look for it

Comment: How does `['1/2021', '1/2021', '12/2020'].concat(['2/2021', '3/2021', '1/2021'])` return `['12/2020', '1/2021', '2/2021', '3/2021']`. Your interpreter is broken.

Comment: @NewProgrammer you really need to use those arrays as **dates1**, **dates2**, **values1**, **values2** and **dates**? What about using a dictionary instead, as spyder1329 mentioned? I can show you an example if you like to.

Comment: @killer I would like to see an example, please

Comment: @NewProgrammer I think that I was too late. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break down the algorithm into the smallest steps, then order the steps after each other:

```js
const dates1 = ['1/2021', '1/2021', '12/2020'];
const values1 = ['-2500', '-150', '-10000'];

const dates2 = ['2/2021', '3/2021', '1/2021'];
const values2 = ['3000', '1000', '3000'];

// summing the arrays & keeping track of how
// the values should be ordered
const reduceArr = ({ dates, values }) => {
  const reduced = dates.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    if (typeof a[c] === 'undefined') a[c] = 0
    a[c] += Number(values[i])
    return a
  }, {})
  const filteredDates = [...new Set([...dates])]
  const filteredValues = filteredDates.map(date => reduced[date])
  return {
    filteredDates,
    filteredValues,
  }
}

// merging the different dates arrays
const mergeDates = ({ dates1, dates2 }) => {
  return [...new Set([...dates1, ...dates2])]
}

// time-sorting the merged arrays
const sortDates = ({ dates }) => {
  return [...dates].sort((a, b) => {
    const [m1, y1] = a.split('/')
    const [m2, y2] = b.split('/')
    return new Date(y1, m1, 1) - new Date(y2, m2, 1)
  })
}

// mapping values based on the orders &
// adding 0 if no value is found
const mapToDates = ({ sortedDates, reducedArr }) => {
  return sortedDates.map(date => {
    const idx = reducedArr.filteredDates.indexOf(date)
    return idx === -1 ? 0 : reducedArr.filteredValues[idx]
  })
}

// actually executing the steps:
const mergedDates = mergeDates({ dates1, dates2 })
const sortedDates = sortDates({ dates: mergedDates })

const reducedArr1 = reduceArr({ dates: dates1, values: values1 })
const mapValues1 = mapToDates({ sortedDates, reducedArr: reducedArr1 })

const reducedArr2 = reduceArr({ dates: dates2, values: values2 })
const mapValues2 = mapToDates({ sortedDates, reducedArr: reducedArr2 })

console.log('mapValues1', mapValues1)
console.log('mapValues2', mapValues2)
```

Comment: @NewProgrammer I'm glad that I could help

Comment: Wow, really thanks again, it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need is that:

```js
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var a = this.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }
    return a;
};

stringToDate = function(str) {
    return str.substring(str.search("/")+1, str.search("/")+5) + "-" + (Number(str.substring(0, str.search("/"))) < 10 ? '0' : '') + str.substring(0, str.search("/") ) + "-15T00:00:00Z";
}

dateToString = function(dt) {
    dt = new Date(dt);
  return (1 + dt.getMonth()) + "/" + dt.getFullYear() ;
}

var dates1 = [stringToDate('1/2021'), stringToDate('1/2021'), stringToDate('12/2020')];
var values1 = ['-2500', '-150', '-10000'];
var dates2 = [stringToDate('2/2021'), stringToDate('3/2021'), stringToDate('1/2021')];
var values2 = ['3000', '1000', '3000'];

var dates_out = dates1.concat(dates2).unique().sort();
var values1_out = new Array(dates_out.length);
var values2_out = new Array(dates_out.length);

dates_out.forEach((dt, i) => {
    dates_out[i] = dateToString(dates_out[i]);
    values1_out[i] = 0;
  values2_out[i] = 0;
    dates1.forEach((dt1, i1) => {
    if (dt1 === dt) {
        if (values1_out[i] != undefined)
            values1_out[i] = values1_out[i] + Number(values1[i1]);
      else 
        values1_out[i] = Number(values1[i1]);
    }  
  });
  dates2.forEach((dt2, i2) => {
    if (dt2 === dt) {
        if (values2_out[i] != undefined)
            values2_out[i] = values2_out[i] + Number(values2[i2]);
      else 
        values2_out[i] = Number(values2[i2]);
    }  
  });
});
console.log(dates_out);
console.log(values1_out);
console.log(values2_out);
```

I don't know if this is the best solution. I would create dictionaries to work with the data.
I understood that you need to order the dates (the first result being 12/2020 instead of 1/2021). I also understood that you need the dates as a string, but if you need the date as a datatype, you can remove the part where I convert it back to a string.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution in python, conversion to javascript should be straight forward.  1. build a list of tuples for dates1/values1 and dates2/values2.  2. Get a list of unique dates. 3. Reduce the tuple lists to a dictionary accumulating on the key which is the date. 4. Using the dates list and the dictionaries create the result value1 and 2 list.

```
def ReduceToDictionary(tuples):
    dict={}
    for item in tuples:
        key = item[0]
        value = item[1]
        if key in dict:
            dict[key] += float(value)
        else:
            dict[key] = float(value)
    return dict

 def BuildList(dates,dict):
     result_values=[]
     for date in dates:
        if date in dict:
             val=dict[date]
             result_values.append(val)
        else:
             val=0
             result_values.append(val)
    return result_values
def StrToDate(string):
    groups=re.match('(\d{1,2})[/](\d{4})',string)
    year=int(groups[2])
    month=int(groups[1])
    return(datetime.datetime(year,month,1))
    
dates1 = ['1/2021', '1/2021', '12/2020']
values1 = ['-2500', '-150', '-10000']

dates2 = ['2/2021', '3/2021', '1/2021']
values2 = ['3000', '1000', '3000']

tuple1=[(StrToDate(dates1[i]),values1[i]) for i in range(len(dates1))]
tuple2=[(StrToDate(dates2[i]),values2[i]) for i in range(len(dates2))]

dates=sorted(set(list(map(StrToDate,dates1))+list(map(StrToDate,dates2))))

dict1=ReduceToDictionary(tuple1)
dict2=ReduceToDictionary(tuple2)

result_values1=BuildList(dates,dict1)
result_values2=BuildList(dates,dict2)

date_string=[date.strftime("%Y/%m") for date in dates]
print(date_string)
print(result_values1)    
print(result_values2)
```

output:

```
['2020/12', '2021/01', '2021/02', '2021/03']
[-10000.0, -2650.0, 0, 0]
[0, 3000.0, 3000.0, 1000.0]
```